# Are there online ebooks of English translations of ancient Indian cookbooks?

Tags: scripture, food, ayurveda, translation

Ancient Indian cookbooks draw exquisitely from Ayurvedic scriptures and apply it to everyday cooking. This is very important from the view point of preservation of both health and culture.

There are four such available books

1. Manollasa 1130 AD
2. Paka Darpana 1200 AD
3. Soopa Shastra 1508 AD
4. Bhojana Kuthuhala 1675 AD

Are there more such ancient cookbooks available?

If present please give the link to Online pdf verdions of English translations of the above books.

Comment: It will be much better and you will have more chances to get an answer if you post the question on Literature Stack Exchange. - https://literature.stackexchange.com/  There is also a tag named historical context there under which you can post.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar thanks for the suggestion. I have asked there https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18698/12977

Comment: Any reason that my answer has not been accepted? Are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: @GIRIBLR sorry it was a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Majority of the cookbooks (and other cookbooks) [are available here](https://peppertrail.com/intriguing-stories/).

Paka darshana of Nala [is available](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/paka-darpana-of-nala-ancient-book-on-indian-cuisine-NAI245/). Some excerpts [are available here](https://peppertrail.com/pakadarpana-culinary-repertoire-of-king-nala/).

Bhojana Kuthuhala [is available](https://www.amazon.in/Bhojankutuhalam-Acharya-Balkrishna-ebook/dp/B07DJ67QDC). The online edition [is here](https://peppertrail.com/bhojanakuthuhalam-part-i-17th-century/).

Soopa Shastra [is available](https://peppertrail.com/soopa-shastra-of-mangarasa-part-ii-recipes-for-sweet-and-savory-breads-and-snacks/). See the [online edition](https://peppertrail.com/soopa-shastra-of-mangarasa-culinary-traditions-of-medieval-karnataka-1508-a-d/).

Mānasollāsa is extensively discussed in this book,
[Indian Food: A Historical Companion](http://libgen.li/ads.php?md5=3808d13114bd7d54cf9c39fbe934ff40). This book is available in library genesis and the online edition is [available here](https://peppertrail.com/manasollasa-refresher-of-the-mind-by-king-somesvara-iii-1129-a-d/).

Comment: I'm so sorry, I must have been more clear, my fault, I was actually asking for online ebook links like from Archive org etc.

Comment: OP is asking for ebooks that are available for free online reading. Maybe you can edit your answer accordingly

Comment: @user1993 He changed the question after I answered. Initially the question was only about the books. I don't think it is right for you to downvote my answer without understanding this fact.

Comment: @MrGreenGold Thanks for the clarification. I have now provided the online editions of the books.

Comment: @GIRIBLR oh, good to know. I changed my vote. Thanks for the updated links